# Given a string, return a string

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

So basically I want to return the string, with a message.

This is what I have so far, why am I getting undefined for the name back I have a series of test that run, and it's supposed to return a empty strong for the first test.

```
export const twoFer = (name) => {

  let saying = "One for" + name + "," + "One for me"
  let greeting = saying

  if (name === '') {
    let greeting = "One for you, One for me"
  } else {
    let greeting = "One for" + name + ",One for me"
  }


  return greeting;
};
```

I thought it would be useful to provide the tests as well so..

```
import { twoFer } from './two-fer'

describe('twoFer()', () => {
  test('no name given', () => {
    expect(twoFer()).toEqual("One for you, one for me.")
  })

  xtest('a name given', () => {
    expect(twoFer("Alice")).toEqual("One for Alice, one for me.")
  })

  xtest('another name given', () => {
    expect(twoFer("Bob")).toEqual("One for Bob, one for me.")
  })
})
```

EDIT Final Solution:

```
export const twoFer = (name = null) => {
  if (!name) {
    return "One for you, one for me."
  } else {
    return "One for " + name + "," + " one for me."
  }
};
```

Comment: I think you should make the string case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `name` is not an empty string, it is `undefined`. Instead, try `!name`, which will be truthy for `undefined`, empty string, `null`, etc.

```js
const twoFer = (name=null) => {
  if (!name) {
    return "One for you, One for me"
  } else {
    return "One for " + name + ", One for me"
  }
};

console.log(twoFer());
console.log(twoFer(''));
console.log(twoFer('bob'));
```

Comment: I am still receiving back undefined from the test .

Answer (score 2):

Scope issue, consider these two cases:

```js
const twoFer = (name) => {

  let saying = "saying is now greeting " + name
  let greeting = saying

  if (!name) {
    let greeting = "this wont set greeting, because let is in if()'s scope"
  } else {
    let greeting = "this also wont set greeting"
  }


  return greeting;
};
console.log(twoFer('foo'))
```

removing `let`

```js
const twoFer = (name) => {

  let saying = "saying is now greeting " + name
  let greeting = saying

  if (name === '') {
      greeting = "One for you, One for me"
  } else {
      greeting = "One for" + name + ",One for me"
  }

  return greeting;
};
console.log(twoFer('foo'))
```

Is alot of unnecessary code it can be done with one line:

```
const twoFer = name => `One for ${name || 'you'}, One for me`
```